# (MATLAB) Colormap for video/animation

Tags: image-processing, video, video-processing, color-mapping

I have some code that produces a series of grayscale images. I am then able to save the images individually in a loop and save them with a colormap applied. i.e.

```
file = sprintf('image_%04d.png',x);
imwrite(image1,jet,file,'png');
```

So i get my images out the other end and they have the correct colormapping which is colormap(jet).

However, when in my next program, I try to cobble these images together to form a short animation (yes I know I should just make the movie in the same loop as above), I get a grayscale movie!!! How does that happen when the source images are color?

Further more I notice that if I load an individual image and then type:

```
imshow(A)
```

i get a grayscale image too! but if I type:

```
image(A)
```

it gives me what I wanted, which is the colormapped image.

Why does it do this? 
how can I get it to make a movie with the correct colormap? 
and is there a way I can add the colormap to the image before saving it (as above I add the map during imwrite)?

p.s. I have tried using :

```
video = videowriter(VideoFileName,'MPEG-4')
video.Colormap = jet  (or) colormap(jet) or 'jet'
```

matlab doesnt like that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex,
VideoWriter has a profile called 'Indexed AVI' which will allow you to save the image with the colormap information. You can use the code below:

```
vwObj = VideoWriter('myfile.avi', 'Indexed AVI');
vwObj.Colormap = jet(256);
open(vwObj);
writeVideo(vwObj, image1);   % Repeat for all images that you want
close(vwObj);
```

MPEG-4 files do not accept a Colormap property. However you can specify a colormap at the time of writing by supplying a MATLAB frame as bellow:

```
vwObj = VideoWriter('myfile', 'MPEG-4');
open(vwObj);
f.cdata = image1;
f.colormap = jet(256);
% The colormap will be applied before writing the data to the MPEG4 file
writeVideo(vwObj, f); 
close(vwObj);
```

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: Hi Dinesh,

Thank you, these both work a treat. Will stick with the MPEG-4 one for the smaller file size. Brilliant, thanks again.