# Matlab - Create a compressed colored video

Tags: matlab, video, colors, compression

I use `videoWriter`from MatLab to get output of my computations. My problem is videos created like this are too heavy. 7k frame, 1000x300 pixels each frames, weight about 2GB, which is a way too much.

I need some color on my videos, so I do:

```
 v=VideoWriter(vidName, 'Indexed AVI');
 v.FrameRate=25;

 map=[ 0 0 0       % (1) Black
       1 0 0       % (2) Red
       1 1 1       % (3) White
       0 1 0       % (4) Green
       0 0 1       % (5) Blue
       1 0 1 ];    % (6) Purple
 v.Colormap=map;
 open(v);
```

[The documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) sais that `Indexed AVI` video can not be compressed, and `Motion JPEG 2000` videos can be compressed, but it can not be colored. Is it wright?

For compressed and colored videos, it seems that there is the `MPEG-4` type. There is the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277333/matlab-colormap-for-video-animation) who talks about it. But I do not understand what is `f` (what type of object it is,...). Also, the data he puts in it is an image (I guess created by a MatLab function). But I only have a grid, which represent each pixels. Can I directly use this grid to set the data of `f`?

EDIT:

The way I store the data:

```
grid=ones(1000, 300);
...
% Some computation
...
writeVideo(v, grid);
```

Comment: I am confused by the start of your post. You seem to start describing a problem related to compression, that your data is too uncompressed and you want it smaller. However, you suddenly change the topic, and mention you want color on your videos. Did the first videos not have color? Why not, its a video, I am almost sure that its always colored (even if it may not look like for you, the data is). What  I mean is, I dont really know what is your actual problem. You ask about some solutions you though, but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? better compression? Lack of color?

Comment: The `f` argument in the linked thread is a `frame`. Look at the [`getframe`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) function to understand what it is. And read the last chapter "_Create AVI File from Animation_" from the [`VideoWriter`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) documentation, they use `frame` objects in this example.

Comment: Personnally, I don't bother compressing in MATLAB. I create my videos (even if they get large) in MATLAB, then I simply use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to compress/resize/reencode them to the format I want.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: yes my problem is about compression. But from what I understand, the `Motion JPEG 2000` type support compression, but not color. And if it does support color, I don't know how, because we can not put a `colormap` in it.

Comment: @Hoki: Thanks for your answer. But I don't plot/create any figure, so i can not get the frame from it. I just have a grid (a matrix) of integer values, which represent a value of the color map. Is there any way (simpler, more direct) to create a video with color and compression?

Comment: Can you add the original way you are storing the data?

Comment: @Phantom The code above, the one that creates the videoWritter, is that the one you use to generate big files? the `indexed AVI` one? According to the docs, all profiles, but 'Indexed AVI' and 'Grayscale AVI' can use color.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Yes it's the `Indexed AVI`. It's strange that grayscale can use color, but according to the docs it has as much color channels as indexed. So your wright. But, both do not support compression, so I don't understand how grayscale can help me.

Comment: All profiles but Garyscale and indexed. So all can use color, but not those 2. Just try 'MPEG-4' or some of the others.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Okay, but is there a way to use `MPEG-4` much simpler than creating an image from my grid, then getting the frame of the image and then writing the frame into the video?

Comment: That's a separate question than the one in the post

Comment: @AnderBiguri: no. If you look, it's want I asked in the paragraph about MPEG, and in my reply to Hoki!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an indexed color video, and the lossy codecs available in VideoWriter do not support indexed frames. They do, however, support RGB frames. You therefore need to convert each frame to RGB using the ind2rgb function, before encoding it.

Comment: If you create a struct with fields cdata and colormap and pass it into writeVideo function of VideoWriter, it should be able to write all supported file formats including MPEG-4 files. BTW MPEG-4 writing is supported on Windows and Mac.

Comment: @DineshIyer If that's the case, it should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a struct with fields cdata and colormap and pass it into writeVideo function of VideoWriter, it should be able to write all supported file formats including MPEG-4 files. BTW MPEG-4 writing is supported on Windows and Mac.